# Merge 2 dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, mutable

I have 2 dictionaries.

```
dict1={('SAN RAMON', 'CA'): 1, ('UPLAND', 'CA'): 4, ('POUGHKEESIE', 'NY'): 3, ('CATTANOOGA', 'TN'): 1}

dict2={('UPLAND', 'CA'): 5223, ('PORT WASHING', 'WI'): 11174, ('PORT CLINTON', 'OH'): 6135, ('GRAIN VALLEY', 'MO'): 10352, ('GRAND JUNCTI', 'CO'): 49688, ('FAIRFIELD', 'IL'): 5165}
```

These are just samples, in reality each dict has hundreds of entries. I am trying to merge the two dictionaries and create dict 3 that contains {dict1.values(): dict2.values()} but only if that city appears in both dicts. So, one entry in dict3 would look like

```
{4:5223}   # for 'UPLAND', 'CA' since it appears in both dict1 and dict2
```

This is just a small step in a larger function I am writing. I was going to try something like :

```
for item in dict1.keys():
        if item not in dict2.keys():
            del item
        return dict[(dict1.keys())=(dict2.keys())]
```

I can't figure out how to make sure the number of complaints from dict1 matches the same city it is being referred to in dict2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I think you want [(demo)](http://ideone.com/WOFz9y):

```
dict3 = dict((dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in dict1 if key in dict2)
```

Expanded a little, it looks like this:

```
dict3 = {}
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        dict3[dict1[key]] = dict2[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

The common keys are:

```
set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys())
```

> create dict 3 that contains {dict1.values(): dict2.values()}

This doesn't make sense, dictionaries are key-value pairs... what do you really want? Tip:

```
dict3 = {}
for k in set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys()):
    dict3[dict1[k]]=dict2[k]

{4: 5223}
```

Comment: Just to mention - for common keys - In 2.7 you can do `dict1.viewkeys() & dict2`

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way would be to check each key in one for membership in the other:

```
result = {}
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        result[dict1[key]] = dict2[key]
```

You could also try converting them into a `set` or `frozenset` and taking their intersection, but it's not clear to me whether that will be faster or not:

```
keys_in_both = frozenset(dict1) & frozenset(dict2)
result = dict((dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in keys_in_both)
```